# Why is my stomach like a Baloon but flat when i flex?

Tags: abdominals, stomach

I was always very skinny as a kid, as I got older 21-22 I went to Australia and ate a shit ton of food, I got a little fat I can say, coming back to my home country the diet is different so I wasn't eating as much, I've lost quite a bit of weight I'm not fat atleast I don't think so.

I'm currently 79kg with a height of 6foot or 183cm
But for a long while now I have had this issue with my stomach where it literally looks like a balloon but when I flex my abs I have a fairly slim stomach, I went to a doctor to see if I had water in my abdomen and I don't, also he said I have very little fat and no Verisiral fat.
He did mention that I might have relaxed abs or weak core which is why all the things in my stomach hang out.
I've also got it looked at and it has nothing to do with my pelvic rotation, my posture is close to perfect as told by a professional.

I'm not sure I hope somone here could help me figure this out.[image: My stomach Flexed and relaxed]